# Missing RAM problem

Tags: ram, bios, hibernate

I have a Ryzen 5950x with 32GB and 64GB. In both cases, Ubuntu is reporting 2-3GB less. BIOS is up to date.

It would be great to claim those 2-3GB memory back and put them to a good use. The CPU does not have integrated graphics.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62Gi         9Gi        44Gi       6.0Mi       7.8Gi        52Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[    0.062647] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.062649] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.062650] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09d1f000-0x09ffffff]
[    0.062651] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20dfff]
[    0.062652] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0b000000-0x0b01ffff]
[    0.062653] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8f860000-0x8f860fff]
[    0.062654] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8f86f000-0x8f86ffff]
[    0.062655] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8f870000-0x8f870fff]
[    0.062656] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x8f88f000-0x8f88ffff]
[    0.062657] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc3482000-0xc3482fff]
[    0.062658] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc70bc000-0xc70c1fff]
[    0.062659] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc8c52000-0xc8c52fff]
[    0.062660] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xca615000-0xcaa13fff]
[    0.062661] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcaa14000-0xcabc4fff]
[    0.062661] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcabc5000-0xcaefafff]
[    0.062662] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcaefb000-0xcbbfefff]
[    0.062663] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcd000000-0xcfffffff]
[    0.062663] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd0000000-0xefffffff]
[    0.062664] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.062664] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfd1fffff]
[    0.062665] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd200000-0xfd2fffff]
[    0.062665] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd300000-0xfd5fffff]
[    0.062666] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd600000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.062666] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd800000-0xfe9fffff]
[    0.062667] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfea00000-0xfea0ffff]
[    0.062667] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfea10000-0xfeb7ffff]
[    0.062668] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfeb80000-0xfec01fff]
[    0.062668] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec02000-0xfec0ffff]
[    0.062669] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec10000-0xfec10fff]
[    0.062669] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec11000-0xfec2ffff]
[    0.062670] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec30000-0xfec30fff]
[    0.062670] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec31000-0xfecfffff]
[    0.062670] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed00fff]
[    0.062671] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed01000-0xfed3ffff]
[    0.062671] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff]
[    0.062672] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed45000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.062672] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xfed8ffff]
[    0.062673] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed90000-0xfedc1fff]
[    0.062673] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedc2000-0xfedcffff]
[    0.062674] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd0000-0xfedd3fff]
[    0.062674] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd4000-0xfedd5fff]
[    0.062675] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd6000-0xfeffffff]
[    0.062675] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
```

Just a guess, could that be the memory area reserved for hibernation/suspend?? If so, are we able to disable it?

I'm running 21.04 with 5.11.0-22-generic kernel.

Thanks!

Comment: *could that be the memory area reserved for hibernation/suspend?? If so, are we able to disable it?* No. There's no memory reserved for suspension (RAM is kept "alive") and swap, not RAM, is used for hibernation. The difference you noticed is system reserved memory that is always reserved proportionally to the full amount and unrelated to VRAM. Whether or not you have a dGPU with its own memory there's always the system reserved memory. The difference is having more or less (more if using an iGPU without dedicated RAM, less otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Most linux OSses calculate RAM in Gibibytes, not gigabytes. My 16GB computer only has 15.4GiB of RAM (or so). The RAM is there and usable, but a GiB is bigger so the number shown to you is smaller (and 64GB is indeed about 62GiB)

Comment: From Wikipedia it states "With these prefixes, a memory module that is labeled as having the size "1GB" has one gibibyte (1GiB) of storage capacity."

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this, but the error might be in your calculations.
You see, a GiB is not equal to a GB. GiB stands for Gibibyte, whereas GB stands for Gigabyte. 64 GB of RAM, is actually about 59 GiB.

With smaller amounts of ram, this doesn't make much of a difference, but in your case it does. 62GiB actually amounts to 66GB.
I am guessing that extra 2 or so GB comes from a swap file/partition

Comment: From Wikipedia it states "With these prefixes, a memory module that is labeled as having the size "1GB" has one gibibyte (1GiB) of storage capacity."

Comment: Trying installing the linux PAE headers and rebooting. It might be an addressing problem.